# JSON API Error- The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.- in iOS, swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have JSON data string structure like,

```
data: {
"items": [
    {
      "kind": "customsearch#result",
      "title": "XHAOYEAHX 40,60,110,150pcs Shoes Charms Fits ... - Amazon.com",
      "snippet": "Buy XHAOYEAHX 40, 60, 110, 150pcs Shoes Charms Fits for Croc Clog Shoes \nWristband Bracelet Party Girls Boys Gifts (Fixed Designs 100pcs) and other ...",
      "pagemap": {
        "scraped": [
          {
            "image_link": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91H%2BUO%2BMDQL._AC_UY395_.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "cse_image": [
          {
            "src": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91H%2BUO%2BMDQL._AC_UY395_.jpg"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]}
```

I tried to call the data model structure as:

```
 struct Items: Codable {
        var title:String?
        var snippet:String?
        var pagemap : PageMap?
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case title = "title"
            case snippet = "snippet"
            case pagemap = "pagemap"
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
               do {
                   let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                    title = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
                    snippet = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .snippet)
                   pagemap = try values.decode(PageMap.self, forKey: .pagemap)
                  
               } catch {
                   print(error.localizedDescription)
               }
           }
    }
    struct PageMap: Codable {
        var cse_image: [Thumbnail]?
       private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case cse_image = "cse_image"
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            do {
                let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                cse_image = try values.decode([Thumbnail].self, forKey: .cse_image)
               
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    struct Thumbnail: Codable {
        let src: String?
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case src = "src"
        }
        
    }
```

When I tried to call this structure and get the data from src string for image through `dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase`, shows error that data couldn't be read, because its missing, where did I go wrong?

```
  let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=shoes&key=myID&cx=ursearchID")!
       let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
           if let error = error {
               print("error: \(error)")
           } else {
               if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                   print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
               }
            if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("data: \(dataString)")
              
              do{
                let jsonStr = dataString
                 let dec = JSONDecoder()
                    dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                 let res = try dec.decode(Data.self, from: jsonStr.data(using:.utf8)!)
              
                // self.items = [res]
                 for shop in res.items{
                    
                    self.shoptitle.append(shop.title!)
                    self.shopsnippet.append(shop.snippet!)
                     self.items.append(shop)
                    print(shop.snippet)
                    print(shop.pagemap?.cse_image)
                    if shop.pagemap?.cse_image != nil {
                        for info in (shop.pagemap?.cse_image!)! {
                        print(info.src)
                    }
                    }
                 }
                 
                 }
                 catch let error as NSError {
                     print("\(error)")
                 }
            }
           
              
           }
       }
       task.resume()
```

Comment: your JSON data, not perfect

Comment: Your root object is definitely not `Data.self`. And **never** `print(error.localizedDescription)`  in a `Codable` context. Print only the `error` instance. And most of your code in the structs is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the `Codable` models that you're using is missing the root level object of the *JSON*. So, you must use

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let items: [Items]
}

struct Items: Codable {
    let title:String?
    let snippet:String?
    let pagemap : PageMap?
}

struct PageMap: Codable {
    let cseImage: [Thumbnail]?
}

struct Thumbnail: Codable {
    let src: String?
}
```

**Important:**

1. No need for `enum CodingKeys` if the property names exactly match the *JSON* keys.
2. No need for `init(from:)` if you're not doing any specific parsing.
3. Don't use `var` when not required. Use `let` instead while declaring the properties.
4. If you're using `convertFromSnakeCase` while parsing, you must create the property names in *camel-case* (without underscore).

Next, your parsing code in `URLSession` must go like,

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let res = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
        //rest of the code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes here:

1. You're converting `jsonStr` to `Data` again when you already have `data`.
2. If you're using `convertFromSnakeCase` all the snake-case keys will be converted to camel-case keys eg: `cse_image` -> `cseImage`.
3. `Items`, `PageMap` don't need custom `CodingKeys` or `init(from decoder: Decoder)`.
4. Your `JSON` is one level deeper, So, you need to create a bounding `struct` like this:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    var items: [Items]
}
```

5. `dec.decode(Data.self...` tries to decode `Data` type you need to try to decode `Response`.

```
try dec.decode(Response.self, from: data)
```